# The difference between Stream ID and Measurement ID in the data stream of Google Analytics 4 (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics-4

Is Stream ID of universal analytics changed to Measurement ID in Google Analytics 4 (GA4)? So, in the data stream of Google Analytics 4, is Stream ID and Measurement ID displayed together? What is the difference between Stream ID and Measurement ID in the data stream of Google Analytics 4 (GA4) and what is the role of each?

I want to know the relationship between Stream ID and Measurement ID. Measurement ID is an ID that is needed to send data to and from GTM, but I want to know why there is a Stream ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing UA vs. GA4, Tracking ID of Universal is similar to the Measurement ID in GA4.

The Stream ID is just like any other unique identifier in a database. It is a never changing value to permanently identify the item in question. You can change the stream name at will; you can't change the ID. It really holds no value other than being unique to the stream.

Google says you can use this value to [send data to specific streams](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12332343?hl=en), similar to the Measurement ID. However, I have never done this and always launched tags via GTM with the Measurement ID.

In terms of reporting, the Stream ID is a pre-populated parameter that comes through with each event. So if you have multiple streams being dumped into a single property, you can identify them with their Stream IDs. The Measurement ID is not passed with events.